# How to display alert after AJAX post success.alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, node.js

In my Node application I have used get and post request. Using get just renders the page and using post insert data into MySQL database. Data is inserted properly but after post gets called and alert fade away very quickly.

This is my code from `app.js`:

```
app.get('/Associate', routes.Associate);
app.get('/addAssociate',routes.addAssociate);
app.post('/addAssociate',routes.postAssociate);
```

This is my code from `routes.js`:

```
Associate: function(req, res) {
      sess = req.session;
      var name = req.session.user;
      var username = 'SELECT first_name from user_info where email_id=?';
      if (sess.user) {
          console.log('\n--------------------- Associate ----------------------');

          var db = req.app.get('db')();

          var id = req.query['id'];

          // var newsquery='SELECT * from associate_info';
          var assoquery = 'SELECT associate_id,doctor_id,CONCAT(initial,"  ",first_name,"  ",middle_name,"  ",last_name) As Name,qualification,address_line1,city,state,pincode,email_id,contact_no from associate_info ';
          var redirect = 'Associate_Listing';

          async.parallel({
                  one: function(callback) {
                      db.query(assoquery, function(error, rows, fields, next) {
                          console.log("length-\t", rows.length);
                          callback(error, rows);
                      });
                  },
                  two: function(callback) {
                      db.query(username, [name], function(error, rows, fields, next) {
                          // console.log(rows.length);
                          console.log(rows);
                          callback(error, rows);
                      });
                  }
              },

              function(error, results) {

                  var totalNews = results.one.length;
                  for (var i = 0; i < results.one.length; i++) {
                      if (!(results.one[i].views > 0) || results.one[i].views == null)
                          results.one[i].views = 0;

                      results.one[i].ids = i + 1;
                      //                        if(!(results.one[i].views>0))
                      //                            results.one[i].views=0;
                  }
                  //        console.log("--------",results.one[0].id);
                  res.render(redirect, {
                      error: JSON.stringify(1),
                      from_period: 0,
                      to_period: 0,
                      state: JSON.stringify("All States"),
                      user2: "Dr" + " " + JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results.two[0]["first_name"])),
                      user: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.session.user)),
                      Associate: results.one,
                      str_journal: JSON.stringify(results.one),
                      user_type_id: req.session.user_type_id,
                      totalJournals: JSON.stringify(totalNews)
                  });

              });
      } else {
          res.redirect('/login');
      }
  },


  // addJournal:function(req,res){
  addAssociate: function(req, res) {
      console.log('\n-------------------- addAssociate ----------------------\n');
      var name = req.session.user;
      var db = req.app.get('db')();
      var username = 'SELECT first_name from user_info where email_id=?';
      if (req.session.user) {
          async.parallel({
                  one: function(callback) {
                      db.query(username, [name], function(error, rows, fields, next) {
                          console.log("length-\t", rows.length);
                          callback(error, rows);
                      });
                  }
              },
              function(error, results) {
                  res.render('addAssociate', {
                      user: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.session.user)),
                      // cases : results.one,
                      user2: "Dr" + " " + JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results.one[0]["first_name"])),
                      user_type_id: req.session.user_type_id,
                      //                    totalNews :JSON.stringify(totalNews)                
                  })
              });

      } else {
          res.redirect('/login');
          // res.redirect('addAssociate');
      }
  },


  postAssociate: function(req, res) {
      console.log('\n-------------------- postAssociate ----------------------\n');

      var db = req.app.get('db')();
      // res.send('Username: ' + req.body.doctorName);
      // var title = req.body.title;
      // var created =req.body.created;
      // initial : req.body.doctorName,
      // var id=1;

      // var dateArray=created.split('/');

      // var finalDate=""+dateArray[2]+"/"+dateArray[1]+"/"+dateArray[0];
      // var date1=new Date(finalDate);
      var initial;
      var first_name;
      var middle_name;
      var last_name;
      var qualification;
      var address_line1;
      var address_line2;
      var city;
      var state;
      var pincode;
      var email_id;
      var contact_no;
      var Uname = req.session.user;

      var post = {


          initial: req.body.initial,
          first_name: req.body.first_name,
          middle_name: req.body.middle_name,
          last_name: req.body.last_name,
          qualification: req.body.qualification,
          address_line1: req.body.address_line1,
          address_line2: req.body.address_line2,
          city: req.body.city,
          state: req.body.state,
          pincode: req.body.pincode,
          email_id: req.body.email_id,
          contact_no: req.body.contact_no,
          status: 1,


      };
      console.log('--------------------' + initial)

      console.log(initial);
      console.log(post);


      db.query('SELECT * from user_info where email_id= ? ', [Uname], function(error, rows, fields) {
          if (error) {
              console.log(error);

          } else {
              console.log('name------------' + Uname);
              console.log('rows---------' + rows.length);

              for (var i in rows) {
                  console.log('----------hhh---' + rows[i].doctor_id);
              }
              db.query('INSERT INTO associate_info SET doctor_id=' + rows[i].doctor_id + ', creation_date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), ? ', post, function(error, result) {
                  console.log('inside if');
                  if (error) {
                      console.log(error);
                      res.status(200).send({
                          success: 3,
                          error: error
                      });
                      return;
                  }

                  console.log('Associate added successfully.');

              });


          }

      });

  },
```

this is jquery ajax code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#save").click(function() {

          var initial = $("#doctorName").val();
          var first_name = $("#firstName").val();
          var middle_name = $("#middleName").val();
          var last_name = $("#lastName").val();
          var qualification = $("#qualification").val();
          var address_line1 = $("#address1").val();
          var address_line2 = $("#address2").val();
          var city = $("#city").val();
          var state = $("#state").val();
          var pincode = $("#pincode").val();
          var email_id = $("#email").val();
          var contact_no = $("#mobile").val();

          var dr = /^[a-zA-Z]+\.$/;
          var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
          var zipexp = /^[0-9]{1,6}$/;
          var mobileexp = /^(\+91-|\+91|0)?\d{10}$/;
          var emailexp = /^[A-Z0-9_'%=+!`#~$*?^{}&|-]+([\.][A-Z0-9_'%=+!`#~$*?^{}&|-]+)*@[A-Z0-9-]+(\.[A-Z0-9-]+)+$/i;


          // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
          var dataString = 'initial=' + initial + '&first_name=' + first_name + '&middle_name=' + middle_name + '&last_name=' + last_name + '&qualification=' + qualification + '&address_line1=' + address_line1 + '&address_line2=' + address_line2 + '&city=' + city + '&state=' + state + '&pincode=' + pincode + '&email_id=' + email_id + '&contact_no=' + contact_no;
          if (initial == '' || first_name == '' || middle_name == '' || last_name == '' || qualification == '' || address_line1 == '' || address_line2 == '' || city == '' || state == '' || pincode == '' || email_id == '' || contact_no == '') {
              alert("Please Fill All Mandatory Fields");
              return false;
          } else if (!initial.match(alphaExp) && !initial.match(dr)) {
              alert("please insert valid initial");
              $("#doctorName").val('');
              document.getElementById('doctorName').focus();
              return false;
          } else if (!first_name.match(alphaExp)) {
              alert("please insert valid first name");
              $("#firstName").val('');
              document.getElementById('firstName').focus();
              return false;
          } else if (!middle_name.match(alphaExp)) {
              alert("please insert valid middle name");
              $("#middleName").val('');
              document.getElementById('middleName').focus();
              return false;
          } else if (!last_name.match(alphaExp)) {
              alert("please insert valid last name");
              $("#lastName").val('');
              document.getElementById('lastName').focus();
              return false;
          } else if (!pincode.match(zipexp) || pincode.length != 6) {
              alert("please insert valid pincode");
              $("#pincode").val('');
              document.getElementById('pincode').focus();
              return false;
          } else if (!email_id.match(emailexp)) {
              alert("please insert email id");
              $("#email").val('');
              document.getElementById('email').focus();
              return false;
          } else if (!contact_no.match(mobileexp)) {
              alert("please insert valid contact no");
              $("#mobile").val('');
              document.getElementById('mobile').focus();
              return false;
          } else {
              // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
              $.ajax({
                  type: "post",
                  url: "/addAssociate",
                  // contentType: 'application/json',
                  data: dataString,
                  cache: false,

                  success: function(data) {
                      console.log("data-----------" + data);
                      alert("hi");

                  }

              });
          }
          // return;
          // return false;

      });
  });
```

I want to display an alert after data inserted successfully into database.

Comment: Please add your html code

Comment: hi,after insert you have to use res.send(data) not res.render()..after that in ajax code do render of page ok

Answer (score 0):

Just Try the Following to make some delay.

**jQuery :**

```
               $.ajax({
                     url:'path-to-process',
                     type:'POST',
                     data:{},
                     success:function(){
                             // Content to Display on Success.
                        setTimeout(function () {
                             // Content to Display on Success with delay.
                        }, 800);
                     }
                  });
```

Here, the "setTimeout()" will provide some specified time delay for display your content.

Have a Nice Day !

Comment: Ok,  check "ajax.success()" get triggered or not.  If triggered, Your Ajax call is OK. After, check with console log and change time delay to ensure, whether delay is working or not !

Comment: after post request immediately  get request called two times

Comment: If you use "Class" to identify element, then check duplicates. 
Else Try ".one()"

Comment: data insert successful message log displayed in get method instead of post.and get method called immediately after post.and now xhr.responseText) alert displays in error function.please help.....

Comment: You could better wait for the response instead of waiting. When the request was taking too long (for example due a slow network) it'll error.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/jatuju/edit?js,output

If you are using the plan old JavaScript,you can using the `XMLHttpRequest` status code to determine whether is success or not